# Rails API and axios Content-type: multipart/form-data transforms json payload. Controller can't read it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axios, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image to a Ride model in a rails 7 API app by axios in the frontend.

Before I got the params inside the rails controller like a normal hash:
`{"ride"=>{"id"=>46515, "vehicle"=>"car"}, "controller"=>"rides", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"46515"}`

But when I try to post the data with

```
axios.patch('URL', {ride: payload}, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
}
```

I don't get a normal nested ruby hash with params[:ride] holding the form data but this parameter hash:

`{"ride.id"=>"46515", "ride.vehicle"=>"car", "controller"=>"rides", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"46515"}`

This messes up my controller logic. Can anyone tell me how I can send a multipart/form-data with the normal params?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by just removing the `ride` key in the payload  `{"ride": {"vehicle":"car"}}` and by posting the payload in the 'root' to `{"vehicle":"car"}`

Still I don't understand why this is happening.